# the definition of random variable

Tags: random-variables, definition

If we supposed that X is a random variable, is X - X a random variable? Could the outcome of an event is only 1? Cause X-X has only one outcome, and the possibility of it is 1. How about X + X?

Comment: $X-X$ is a random variable. As you point out, it is identically $0$. That makes it an *uninteresting* random variable, but still a random variable.

Comment: Hi @AndréNicolas, that's interesting that we would still call it a random variable, even though there is no randomness to $X-X$; it is deterministic.

Comment: The function which is identically $0$ is still a function. It is useful to allow "constants" to be random variables. For example $X+2$ is a random variable "because" $X$ and $2$ are.

Comment: Ah, ok got it.  Thanks so much, @AndréNicolas :-)

Comment: You are welcome. In many (real) problems, the right approach to a solution involves combining random variables using the usual algebraic tools, plus other functions such as the exponential function.

Comment: hi @André Nicolas So, a number could be considered as a constant function which is a random variable. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (real-valued) random variable $X$ is formally defined as a function $X : \Omega \to \mathbb R$, where $\Omega$ is the set of outcomes. So, $Y = X - X$ is also a function $\Omega \to \mathbb R$, specifically the zero function: $Y(\omega) = X(\omega) - X(\omega) = 0$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

Note that this is in fact a stronger statement than "$Y=0$ with probability one", which allows for the possibility that $Y(\omega) \neq 0$ on some nonempty subset of $\Omega$ which has probability zero.

One can generally without harm identify $X - X$ with the constant number zero, but technically it is a random variable.

To answer the other question, $Z = X+X$ is simply $2X$, which is of course also a random variable: formally, it is the function $Z : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ defined by $Z(\omega) = X(\omega) + X(\omega) = 2X(\omega)$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: very clear! That makes sense~ Thanks a lot~

Comment: "A (real-valued) random variable X is formally defined as a function X:Ω→R, where Ω is the set of outcomes". This is the most correct definition. Could you please point the source. The definition's in the Sheldon ross book and the Michael J. Evans book are misleading. They define random variable as a mapping from sample space to real number which is not correct. It should have been mapping from events to real number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $X-X$, and $X+X$ are random variables, assuming that $X$ is a random variable.

$X-X$, which is identically $0$, is considered a (discrete) random variable.

Comment: So X-X is a random variable, could we say that X - X = 0 is true? In my point of view, this is not true, because X - X is a random variable, not a number zero. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I see what you are asking.  I think that what you are asking isn't meaningful.  Are you getting this out of a book and / or class notes?  Usually, we would talk about the addition and subtraction with *another* random variable, $Y$, and look at X-Y or X+Y, etc.

Comment: Yes, X-X is $0$ with probability 1, but this is a triviality and isn't meaningful...

Comment: This is one of the questions for next week in-class discussion. I just confused that whether zero could be count as a function. Seems that it could be. Thanks for helping me with that~

Comment: You're welcome @echo0831 -- feel free to up-vote my answer :-)